# Quais cuidados devem ser tomados quando se envia um e-mail via PHP

Tags: php, segurança

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário de contato para meu site, como de costume eu primeiro deixo ele funcional, e depois trabalho na segurança do mesmo.

Em se tratando de um formulário simples, que só vai receber um campo `name`, outro campo `email` e por último um campo `message`; Quais cuidados devem ser tomados com esse formulário em relação a segurança?

Não sou experiente em PHP, mas já li artigos nos informando que formulários que fazem acesso ao banco de dados MySQL podem ser manipulados de tal forma que usuários mal-intencionados possam ter acesso a informações ás quais eles não deveriam ter.

Existe algum perigo assim quando não existe uma interação com o banco de dados?

Eu sei que devo fazer a validação para impedir que o usuário envie um campo vazio por exemplo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creio que os cuidados a serem tomados quando se está enviando e-mails por algum sistema web, são aqueles cuidados comuns bem conhecidos: validar se o e-mail digitado segue realmente um padrão de e-mail (via expressão regular por exemplo), se os campos nome e mensagem não estão vazios e adicionar um **captcha** para evitar que algum script mal intencionado fique enviando e-mails sem parar já é suficiente.

Sobre os artigos que leu de formulários que fazem acesso ao banco serem manipulados, isso nada mais é que a velha conhecida **injeção SQL**, presente em sistemas web no geral e não específico da linguagem PHP.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Formulário não se conectam com a database, ele apenas fornece as informações que serão inseridas no DB. Você precisa validar antes de salvar as informações, verificar se o que recebeu é do tipo correspondente...

SQL Injection ocorre quando você recebe instruções junto a um input e executa a query sem validação. Você pode `conceder acesso` a um sistema de login ou até executar um `DROP TABLE`.
O uso de `PDO` elimina uma porcentagem significativa - o debate é longo.

Você pode ter um input(_GET ou _POST) que salva dados no DB ou em arquivos, dados de login e senha, envio de email... Cada caso é um caso e os dados não vêm unicamente de formulários.

<sub>**filter_var( $emial , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )**</sub>
Não fornece uma validação segura para email. Você precisa validar com uma ER como foi citado.